# FIWARE - IoT Agent - Data for Orion

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I have installed FIWARE on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04) and I am currently trying to work with the IoT Agent, using the HTTPBindings.js (my data is sent via LoRaWAN and I've changed the parseData function in order to use my own data "protocol" [id=1&temp=12&humidity=10], which brings me here to ask 2 questions for someone who is more experienced and can help me with:

```
 function parseData(req, res, next) {
    let data;
    let error;
    let payload;
    let obj; 
      try {
        let newPayload = new Buffer.from(payload, "base64").toString("ascii");
      var ps = newPayload.split("&").reduce((accum, x) => {
        const kv = x.split("=");
        return { ...accum, ...{ [kv[0]]: kv[1] } };
      }, {});
        data = ulParser.parse(newPayload.replace(/&/g, "|").replace(/=/g, "|"));
       
      } catch (e) {
          error = e;
      }
    
      if (error) {
          next(error);
      } else {
          req.ulPayload = data;
          config.getLogger().debug(context, 'Parsed data: [%j]', data);
          next();
      }
    }
```

1. After changing this function, I can't get the data to be updated in the orion/v2/entities.. Would someone explain me how does this work?
2. How can I add a proxy to us`enter code here`e in the Wirecloud? I've created it using the FIWARE servers, but testing on my own, I do not have this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can find a working `docker-compose.yml` for Wirecloud in the following [tutorial](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/application-mashups.html)

Comment: Which IoT Agent are you using - the **IoT Agent for LoRaWAN** or the **IoT Agent for Ultralight**?  The `HTTPBindings.js` file from the Ultralight IoT Agent is assuming comms is over HTTP, not LoRa. As your regex conversion suggests, the `ulParser.js` will read data in assuming Ultralight syntax, but if the binding is listening for the wrong protocol any measures will not be successfully received.

Comment: I'm following the docker-compose.yml that you said, just having some problemas with the NGSI Proxy. What should I put here?

Comment: As for the HTTPBindings, I'm getting the comms via HTTP (not LoRa  integrated). I'm using the said function to convert to the Ultralight syntax. So my problem should be related with the Binding? Somewhere around the "function handleIncomingMeasure"? Thank you Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Configuring NGSI Proxy

The `ngsi-proxy` is configured using environment variables and a `port`.

```yaml
  ngsi-proxy:
    image: fiware/ngsiproxy:1.2.0
    hostname: ngsi-proxy
    container_name: wc-ngsi-proxy
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.14
    expose:
      - "8100"
    ports:
      - "8100:8100"
    environment:
      - PORT=8100
      - TRUST_PROXY_HEADERS=0
```

The NGSI proxy  config in the wirecloud widget is then `http://<host>:<port>` - in this case `http://ngsi-proxy:8100`

### Testing HTTP Binding connectivity

Incoming HTTP measures can be controlled by the `IOTA_HTTP_PORT` Environment variable:

```yaml
iot-agent:
    image: fiware/iotagent-ul:${ULTRALIGHT_VERSION}
    hostname: iot-agent
    container_name: fiware-iot-agent
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
      - orion
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - "4041:4041" 
      - "7896:7896"
    expose:
      - "7896"
    environment:
..etc
      - IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4041
      - IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG 
      - IOTA_HTTP_PORT=7896
      - IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://iot-agent:4041
```

If you ramp up the debug and expose the relevant port, you should be able to send measures directly to your custom IoT Agent and see some sort of response (probably an error) - this can help track down your coding issue.

You can always add additional debug logging to the custom IoT Agent to see how the conversion is working.